# Redundant [connectors] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are two tags, [connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connector) and [connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectors), that seem to be the very definition of redundancy.

I'm not familiar with exactly how the system here works, but if it's possible to have [connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectors) redirect to [connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connector) (as the former has only three questions while the latter has hundreds), that would be ideal. I can obviously clean up the three [connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectors) questions myself; what I'm asking here is to have the redirect instated.

Answer (score 10):

I agree, the connectors tag should be merged with connector. If there are no objections, I will do this in a few days